# OAuth middleware cross-application possible?

Tags: c#, authentication, oauth, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to split my project into three parts. There is the single-page-application, the OAuth-middleware and finally my WebApi.

The user should be able to log in, thats what I need the SPA & middleware for.

Also it should be possible to perform AJAX-requests from JavaScript to my WebApi if the middleware approves (the user is authorized).

Thats how the middleware `Startup.cs` is configured:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
  app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);

  OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions opt = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
  {
    TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Security/Token"),
    ApplicationCanDisplayErrors = true,
    AllowInsecureHttp = true,
    Provider = new OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
    {
      OnValidateAuthorizeRequest = ValidateAuthorizeRequest,
      OnGrantResourceOwnerCredentials = GrantResourceOwnerCredentials,
      OnValidateClientAuthentication = ValidateClientAuthentication,
      OnGrantRefreshToken = GrantRefreshToken,
    },
    RefreshTokenProvider = new AuthenticationTokenProvider
    {
      OnCreate = CreateRefreshToken,
      OnReceive = ReceiveRefreshToken,
    }
  };
  app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(opt);

  OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions _opt = new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions();
  app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(_opt);
}
```

Login already works (I get a 200 Status code when communicating with security/token) and JavaScript calls to resources placed in the middleware also work.

I assume, if this is possible, I have to configure another `Owin Startup.cs` for my WebApi.
What I've done is:

```
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);
        OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions cOpt = new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions();
        cOpt.Realm = "http://localhost:61188/Security/Token"; //auth server
        cOpt.AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active;
        //cOpt.AccessTokenProvider = new AuthenticationTokenProvider();
        cOpt.Provider = new OAuthBearerAuthenticationProvider
        {
            OnValidateIdentity = ValidateIdentity,
            OnRequestToken = RequestToken
        };
        app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(cOpt);
    }
```

Do you have any ideas what to do to make the requests to my WebApi possible?

If you need more of my code, just ask ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the `Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb` reference to my project solved the issue. I'm still getting `Unauthorized`-responses when using `$.ajax`, but angulars `resource` and `http` services are working correctly.

I also could limit the resource servers owin startup action to:

```
app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);
OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions opt = new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions();
app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(opt);
```

Answer (score 0):

We implemented this for our BackOffice single page application. We provide our users a login page in which they enter their credentials. We send them to the authentification server which retuns the request-, refresh token and the expire date. Then we store both in a cookie and in memory (the cookie is used to authenticate the user when he refreshes the page without reentering the credentials).

```
var requestToken, refreshToken, expireDate;

$.ajax({
    method: 'post',
    url: '/api/token',
    data: {
        username: 'John Doe',
        password: 'secret',
        grant_type: 'password'
    },
    success: function(res) {
        requestToken = res.requestToken;
        refreshToken = res.refreshToken;
        expireDate = res.expireDate;
    }
})
```

To request data from webapi the request token is attached to the `Authorization` header.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/api/article',
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer' + token
    }
})
```

To renew the request token a timer is set to the expire date minus some seconds.

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $.ajax({
        method: 'post',
        url: '/token',
        data: {
            refresh_token: refreshToken,
            grant_type: 'refresh_token'
        },
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer' + token
        },
        success: function() {
           // store new token
        }
    });
}, new Date(expireDate) - (new Date()) - 120000);
```

Comment: Yes, this is also how we do it. As I said, the login already works, which means: the user can log in and gets a Bearer token. It will be stored client side and send with every Api-request. My problem is the way to configure the Api. Even if the Api gets the right token, it answers with `401: Unauthorized`. My guess is that's because the Api doesn't/can't communicate with the `Auth-server` due to the wrong Owin configuration.